# How do I get my output for percentage to be two digits?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a clean percentage from this line of code. For example, 50.00% or 61.37%. From this line, I am getting 5000.00% and so on. I have an idea that it has to do with how I am using `format`, but I'm not sure how it is doing this. I tried using `int` and got the desired number, just without the .00 and the % sign.

```
class_males = float(input('Please enter the number of male students registered:')) #Asks for user input of males
class_females = float(input('Please enter the number of female students registered:'))#Asks for user input of females
class_total = int(class_males) + int(class_females) #class total by combining user inputs
m_perc = int(class_males)/int(class_total)* 100 #divide user input of males by class total then multiply by 100 for %
f_perc = int(class_females)/int(class_total)* 100 #divide user input of females by class total then multiply by 100 for %
male_perc = "{:.2%}".format(m_perc) #adds "%" sign after number total 
female_perc = "{:.2%}".format(f_perc) #adds "%" sign after number total 
print('Percentage of males registered:', (male_perc)) #display percent of males 
print('Percentage of females registered:',(female_perc))  #display percent of females
```

If it isn't already clear, I am a beginner. Thank you for any help provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are multiplying by 100 *twice* because the `%` format specifier already does that for you, but you *also* do it yourself, resulting in a multiplication by 10,000 at the end.

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> | Type | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | `'%'` | Percentage. **Multiplies the number by 100** and displays in fixed (`'f'`) format, followed by a percent sign. |

(Emphasis mine.)

The solution resulting in the leanest code is therefore to remove your own multiplication by 100 and just pass the ratio value directly:

```py
m_ratio = int(class_males) / int(class_total) # divide user input of males by class total
f_ratio = int(class_females) / int(class_total) # divide user input of females by class total
male_perc = "{:.2%}".format(m_ratio) # multiplies by 100 and adds "%" sign after number total 
female_perc = "{:.2%}".format(f_ratio) # multiplies by 100 and adds "%" sign after number total
```

Alternatively, you could switch to formatting as float using `f` as explained in [Claudio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73773765/1871033).

Comment: You don't in your answer consider that the purpose of the output was to print the *percentage* value. Suggesting a change of meaning of `m_perc` in code is not the right way of solving the problem with the format template specification.

Comment: And with this, the extra explanation in your answer _is_ warranted :)

Comment: Comments must be at least 15 chars long ... :)  *(I wanted to answer only with `:)`*

Comment: Better would be to suggest `m_ratio =` as the variable name for the assigned value without the multiplication by 100. `m_perc` suggests it is already multiplied by 100.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Small typo: you have placed the % character in the wrong place in the format specification. Put it as follows:

**`"{:6.2f}%"`** ( *instead of `"{:.2%}"`* )

You are getting the wrong result because the '%' sign used as format directive within `{}` formats a number to %-value by multiplication  with 100, adding the % sign at its end.

Alternatively, you could switch to changing your `m_perc`,`f_perc` values to `m_ratio` and `f_ratio` as explained in [CherryDTs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73773691/7711283).

Comment: I wouldn't call it the wrong place. It is the right place for formatting a value as percentage, but it seems the implications of that are not clear to the OP. It would be better to explain what `%` does inside versus outside of the braces and why that matters.

Comment: This is already done in the other answers, so no need to duplicate this. Better to point to another solution compared to the another ones. That the format string is the cause of the problem is known to the OP. The question was *what is wrong with that?* **And this above is actually the only right answer.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with how you are using format (from my testing, although I am also fairly new), but if you stop multiplying by 100 after, it should give proper results.

```
class_males = float(input('Please enter the number of male students registered:')) #Asks for user input of males
class_females = float(input('Please enter the number of female students registered:'))#Asks for user input of females
class_total = int(class_males) + int(class_females) #class total by combining user inputs
m_perc = int(class_males)/int(class_total) #divide user input of males by class total for %
f_perc = int(class_females)/int(class_total)#divide user input of females by class total for %
male_perc = "{:.2%}".format(m_perc) #adds "%" sign after number total 
female_perc = "{:.2%}".format(f_perc) #adds "%" sign after number total 
print('Percentage of males registered:', (male_perc)) #display percent of males 
print('Percentage of females registered:',(female_perc))  #display percent of females
```